# How to get the JDBC Adapter service (SelectSQL) result in a DocumentList in webmethods?

Tags: xml, jdbc, document, webmethods, wm-flow

I am trying to query the database and make an xml document out of the resultSet received and write the same to a file. But it is not executing properly.

The flow I have designed is:

1. Adapter Service
2. LOOP over /results
3. Copy result[] to a tempDoc Generate a XML String from tempDoc using pub.xml:documentToXMLString
4. Convert the said string to bytes using pub.string:stringToBytes
5. Write to a file using a Java Service called
   ISFileSystem.pub:putBytes

The adapter service is fetching the data correctly. Screenshot attached. But after that I think none of the steps are working. I am only getting the output of the Adapter Service. It seems that the "results" Document List is not getting copied as it should in the LOOP step.

Therefore my question is how can I get the output resultset of the Adapter service in a document/documentList? 
I am fairly new in webMethods Development. Can you please help?

[AdapterServiceScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4VcE.png)

[possibleErrorStepScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK2uI.png)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a simple mapping mistake. You are looping over "**results**", but in your pipeline you have a document name "**selctLongDescByIdOutput/results**". I think you service "selectLongDescById" does not map your JDBC Adapter output into the results document list. Or you have to adjust your loop input parameter.

Greetings

Henning

[image: Loop input does not match pipeline values]